# Excel return value that falls within a range

Tags: excel

[image]Table 1 contains Code 1 and the Code 2 that will fall within a set range.

In Table 2 the array formula below in ColF works well:

```
{=INDEX(Table1[Code 1],MATCH(1,(G4<=Table1[Code 2 to])*(G4>=Table1[Code 2 from]),0))}
```

But I am unsure how to add to the above formula to say "DO NOT USE" where Code 2 from / to is blank OR to bring back value where Code 2 is a single value

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with the blanks or any other number that does not fall inside your ranges wrap your formula in IFERROR():

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Code 1],MATCH(1,(G4<=Table1[Code 2 to])*(G4>=Table1[Code 2 from]),0)),"")
```

It is still an array formula so use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to confirm.

To deal with the second problem just put a rediculous large number in the `Code 2 to` space like `1E+99`.

Comment: Thank you for this!